# Random Forest with p>>n and not enough memory

Tags: r, random-forest, ram

I am trying to perform Random Forest classification on genomic data with ~200k predictors and ~20 rows. Predictors have been already pruned for autocorrelation. I tried to use the 'ranger' R package, but it complains it cannot allocate  164Gb vector (I do have 32Gb RAM).

1. Is there any RF implementation that can manage the analysis given
   the available RAM (I would like to avoid increasing the swap)?
2. Should I maybe use a different algorithm (for what I read, RF should
   deal alright with p>>n)?

Answer (score 0):

If it's genomic data, are there a lot of zeroes? If so, you might be able to convert into a sparse matrix, using the `Matrix` package. I believe `ranger` has been able to work with sparse matrices for a while, and this can help a lot with memory issues.

As far as I know, `ranger` is the best R random forest package available for datasets where p >> n.